# Under what conditions does find_package() print a message?

Tags: cmake, build-dependencies, verbose, find-package

The CMake `find_package()` command sometimes prints a message, indication that the package has been found, and possibly the found version.

What are the condition(s) for this message being printed, other than `QUIET` not being used?

Note: Asking about CMake 3.22 in case it matters.

**Edit:** I have now [filed a bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25540) against CMake asking for the ability to print a message even when this is not currently mandated.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this with a few configurations and made the following observations:

1. The version script and the package configuration script or the find script can ignore quiet and print as much as they like; the presence of the `QUIET` option seems more like a suggestion than something enforced by cmake.
2. CMake itself seems to print the version number of unsuitable packages automatically, if no suitable package is found and

   - `REQUIRED` is specified, or
   - `QUIET` isn't specified
3. If a suitable version of the package is found, nothing is printed, regardless of whether `REQUIRED` and/or `QUIET` are present.

*(Tested with the Windows version of CMake 3.22.1. The ["basic signature"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#basic-signature) was used in all tests.)*

Comment: What about the case of a package _being_ found? And no QUIET?

Comment: @einpoklum No prints by default regardless of QUIET/REQUIRED. Added the info to the answer.

Comment: IME most find modules will print the _first_ time they are found (at least if they are using FPHSA, which ~all the built-in ones do). After that, cache variables are created and the printing gets skipped.

Comment: @fabian: That means that the printing I do see is either find scripts, or package config files choosing to print, right?